# How does code push cordova get the path of the cordova project in visual studio team services?

Tags: cordova, azure-devops, code-push

How does code push cordova get the path of the cordova project in visual studio team services for the step to execute cordova prepare command?

Answer (score 0):

The [CodePush - Release (Cordova)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.code-push) task is using the default working directory, and the directory can not be specify for this task.

I add an issue [Can not specity the directory to execute the command code-push release-cordova](https://github.com/Microsoft/code-push-vsts-extension/issues/27), you can follow up.

The work around for now is using **Command Line task** instead. Settings for the Command Line task as below:

Tool: `cd`

Arguments: `path/to/your/cordova/app & code-push login <token> & code-push release-cordova AppName OS`

**Besides:** CodePush task also can parse the variable `Build.SourceDirectory`, so you can define this variable with the value  `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\path\to\cordova\app` in Variables Tab (below is an example).

[image]